# how to clear the html div elements for every for loop in a jsp page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jsp

i have a project to display the sliding images, videos, flash, html page, audio etc on a web page by schedule by schedule. each schedule has few design, every design is nothing but one of these components(video/audio/image/flash/html). am having outer for loop for schedule and inner forloop for designs under the schedules. inner for loop has few conditions to check the type of media and display the corresponding data using html div element on a jsp page. am getting the right path of each designs by using backend java code. what i want now is to clear the div elements for next next schedules. i have tried using subDiv.remove(), it fails to show the videos and displaying the others. seeks your good suggestion to fix this. need to clear the schedules accordingly while new schedule comes in.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" consatent="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>JSP Page</title>

        <!--        <script>-->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="${path}/jsp/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
       // clock function() to display the clock value
    </script>


    <style type="text/css">
        .flags{color:blue;}
        marquee div{float:left; padding:0 0 0 10px;}
    </style>
</head>
<body>

    <div style="position: absolute" id="mainDiv">

        <c:forEach items="${List}" var="schedule" varStatus="status"> <%-- Loop for template(schedule) starts here --%>

            <div id="subDiv">
                <br><br>${status}--------------- Template------------------------------${design.templateId}<br><br>
                <c:forEach items="${schedule.designTabModel}" var="design" varStatus="status1"><%-- Loop for design starts here --%>
                     <% Thread.sleep(5000);%>
                    <div id="subDiv1">
                        <c:choose>

                            <c:when test="${design.ctrType == 'pictureBox'}">
                                <%--<div style="position: absolute; top: ${design.ctrLocationX};left: ${design.ctrLocationY}">--%>
                                <c:forEach items="${design.files}" var="file" varStatus="status">
                                    <%--<img src="${file}" style="position: absolute"--%>
                                    ----------Picture Box template id is: ${design.templateId}<br>
                                    --File - ${file} - Location : X is  - ${design.ctrLocationX} - Y is  - ${design.ctrLocationY}<br>

                                </c:forEach>
                            </c:when>

                            <c:when test="${design.ctrType == 'label'}">

                                ----------Label Box template id is: ${design.templateId}<br>
                                --Text Content: - ${design.ctrText} - Location : X is  - ${design.ctrLocationX} - Y is  - ${design.ctrLocationY}<br>

                                <div id="labelid" class='flags' style="position: absolute; left: ${design.ctrLocationX}; top: ${design.ctrLocationY};">
                                    <MARQUEE BEHAVIOR='SCROLL' HEIGHT='${design.ctrHeight}' WIDTH='${design.ctrWidth}' BGColor='yellow' scrollamount="1" onmouseover="this.stop();" onmouseout="this.start();">
                                        <div id="l1">${design.ctrText}</div>
                                    </MARQUEE>
                                </div>
                            </c:when>

                            <c:when test="${design.ctrType == 'html'}">

                                ----------Html Box template id is: ${design.templateId}<br>
                                --Url: - ${design.ctrText} - Location : X is  - ${design.ctrLocationX} - Y is  - ${design.ctrLocationY}<br>

                                <div id="content" style="position: absolute; left: ${design.ctrLocationX}; top: ${design.ctrLocationY}">
                                    <iframe src="${design.ctrText}" name="frame2" id="frame2" frameborder="0" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" scrolling="auto" onload="" allowtransparency="false" width="${design.ctrWidth}" height="${design.ctrHeight}">
                                    </iframe>
                                </div> 
                            </c:when>


                            <c:when test="${design.ctrType == 'clock'}">

                                ----------Clock Box template id is: ${design.templateId}<br>
                                - Location : X is  - ${design.ctrLocationX} - Y is  - ${design.ctrLocationY}<br>

                                <div id="clockbox" style="position: absolute; background-color:green; border:1px solid black; padding:10px; left: ${design.ctrLocationX}; top: ${design.ctrLocationY}; height: ${design.ctrHeight}; width: ${design.ctrWidth}">                              
                                    <script>GetClock();</script>
                                </div>
                            </c:when>        

                            <c:when test="${design.ctrType == 'audio'}">
                                <c:forEach items="${design.files}" var="file" varStatus="status">
                                    ----------Audio template is: ${design.templateId}<br>
                                    --File - ${file}<br>
                                    <br>

                                </c:forEach>
                            </c:when>

                            <c:when test="${design.ctrType == 'video'}">
                                <c:forEach items="${design.files}" var="file" varStatus="status">
                                    ----------Video template is: ${design.templateId}<br>
                                    --File  - ${file}- Location X is  - ${design.ctrLocationX} - Y is  - ${design.ctrLocationY}<br>
                                    <div id="videofile" style="position: absolute; left: ${design.ctrLocationX}; top: ${design.ctrLocationY}" 
                                         <object width="${design.ctrWidth}" height="${design.ctrHeight}"
                                            type="video/x-ms-asf" 
                                            classid="CLSID:6BF52A52-394A-11d3-B153-00C04F79FAA6">
                                            <param name="autostart" value="1">
                                            <param name="autosize" value="1">
                                            <embed type="application/x-mplayer2" src="${file}" width="${design.ctrWidth}" height="${design.ctrHeight}" autostart="true" showcontrols="true" pluginspage="http://www.microsoft.com/Windows/MediaPlayer/" loop="loop" scale="tofit"></embed>
                                        </object>
                                    </div>
                                </c:forEach>
                            </c:when>

                            <c:when test="${design.ctrType == 'flashMovie'}">
                                <c:forEach items="${design.files}" var="file" varStatus="status">
                                    ----------Flash template is ${design.templateId}<br>
                                    --File name is - ${file} - Location X is  - ${design.ctrLocationX} - Y is  - ${design.ctrLocationY}<br>
                                </c:forEach>
                            </c:when>

                            <c:otherwise>

                            </c:otherwise>
                        </c:choose>
                    </div>

                </c:forEach>

            </div>
                <script>

                   $("#subDiv").remove(); // clearing the schedule

                </script>
        </c:forEach>
    </div>
```

`

Comment: my above code clears for every new schedule, but the video div element not even opening (corresponding design also not appearing on the webpage), any suggestion pls ? also seeks help on the html div code for sliding image ?